Wrap doubles without overhead in Csharp
I'm trying to create a structure that's essentially just a regular double but has a physical unit attached via generics.
My attempts perform terribly, even without generics. Could somebody give me hints how I could make this faster, if possible at all in C#?
I've used
public readonly struct MyDouble
{
    public readonly double Value;

    public MyDouble(double value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public static MyDouble operator +(MyDouble self, MyDouble value)
    {
        return new MyDouble(self.Value + value.Value);
    }

    public static MyDouble operator *(MyDouble self, double value)
    {
        return new MyDouble(self.Value * value);
    }
}

and while mere constructing, storing, and retrieving these is as fast as for doubles, as soon as I use the operators, performance tanks compared to raw double arithmetic.
I reckoned this is just a matter of inlining, but adding [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)] attributes to the operators didn't help at all.
I verified the poor performance using unit tests as well as using JetBrain's dottrace on production runs.
Here is a reproduction using Benchmark Dotnet:
using System;
using System.Linq;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace MyBenchmark;

public readonly struct MyDouble
{
    public readonly double Value;

    public MyDouble(double value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public static MyDouble operator +(MyDouble self, MyDouble value)
    {
        return new MyDouble(self.Value + value.Value);
    }

    public static MyDouble operator *(MyDouble self, double value)
    {
        return new MyDouble(self.Value * value);
    }
}

public class DoubleBenchmark
{
    private const int N = 1_000_000;
    private readonly double[] _data;
    private readonly double[] _workspace;
    private readonly MyDouble[] _typedData;
    private readonly MyDouble[] _typedWorkspace;

    public DoubleBenchmark()
    {
        _data= new double[N];
        _workspace = new double[N];
        _typedWorkspace = new MyDouble[N];
        var rand = new Random(0);
        for (var i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            _data[i] = rand.NextDouble();
        }
        _typedData = _data.Select(x => new MyDouble(x)).ToArray();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public MyDouble TypedDoubles()
    {
        var d = new MyDouble(0);
        for (var i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            d += _typedData[i] * 3;
            _typedWorkspace[i] = d * 2 + new MyDouble(1);
        }
        var e = new MyDouble(0);
        for (var i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            e += _typedWorkspace[i];
        }

        return e;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public MyDouble ManuallyInlinedTypedDoubles()
    {
        var d = new MyDouble(0);
        for (var i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            d = new MyDouble(d.Value + _typedData[i].Value * 3);
            _typedWorkspace[i] = new MyDouble(d.Value * 2 + 1);
        }
        var e = new MyDouble(0);
        for (var i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            e = new MyDouble(e.Value + _typedWorkspace[i].Value);
        }

        return e;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public double Doubles()
    {
        var d = 0d;
        for (var i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            d += _data[i] * 3;
            _workspace[i] = d * 2 + 1;
        }
        var e = 0d;
        for (var i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            e += _workspace[i];
        }
        
        return e;
    }
    
    [Test, Explicit]
    public static void RunBenchmarks()
    {
        BenchmarkRunner.Run<DoubleBenchmark>();
    }
    
    [Test, Explicit]
    public static void EqualResults()
    {
        var a = new DoubleBenchmark();
        Console.WriteLine((a.TypedDoubles().Value, a.Doubles(), a.ManuallyInlinedTypedDoubles().Value));
        if (Math.Abs(a.TypedDoubles().Value - a.Doubles()) > 0 ||
            Math.Abs(a.TypedDoubles().Value - a.ManuallyInlinedTypedDoubles().Value) > 1e-16)
        {
            throw new Exception("Different results");
        }
    }
}

|                      Method |      Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
|---------------------------- |----------:|----------:|----------:|
|                TypedDoubles | 12.205 ms | 0.0170 ms | 0.0142 ms |
| ManuallyInlinedTypedDoubles |  6.158 ms | 0.0063 ms | 0.0055 ms |
|                     Doubles |  3.149 ms | 0.0032 ms | 0.0028 ms |


Just to be sure: you tested with a Release configuration? And what does "terribly" mean, can you show some benchmarking code and measurements?

This isn't about inlining. Raw double arithmetic uses specialized compiler, JIT and CPU optimizations. The JIT compiler could detect multiple double additions and replace them with eg SIMD operations. Your class can't use these. self.Value can't be replaced by the double value - the compiler doesn't even know what that value is until that line runs.

F#'s Units of Measure are actually replaced by the raw value during compilation as this Sharplab.io example shows

@panagiotiskanavos but after you inline everything , what's stopping you from using all those optimizations?

@Klausgütter I was hesitant to add any concrete benchmarking because people here have the habit of getting hung up on details. if anybody thinks the code/snippet/definitions I pasted above should be as fast as raw doubles when used in computations, I'd be happy to she them how it doesn't work out for me, but I don't think anyody does so far?

@panagiotiskanavos if I just do the computations by hand using .Value everywhere and then constructing the MyDouble again at the end, the code is as fast as the raw doubles. So it does seem to be entirely a matter of "compiler doesn't inline in the same way as I can do myself"

On the contrary, if you look at the generated assembly in Sharplab you'll see the code loads the values directly into XMM registers, used by SSE SIMD commands. Your code has to construct a new object though, which requires multiple additional operations. If that takes as long as the addition, you get 50% less performance

BTW if you create another method that just adds Value to itself you'll see that the same SIMD code is generated.

I verified the poor performance using unit tests that doesn't say anything. Running a 100K iteration loop isn't the same as performing the same operation 100K times, due to JIT , caching and warmup effects. The test code can have a significant impact too, eg due to CPU caching. Use BenchmarkDotNet and post the actual benchmark code in the question along with the DBN results. BDN takes care of warmup effects and repeats tests long enough to produce statistically meaningful results.

@PanagiotisKanavos that sentence continues with as well as using JetBrain's dottrace on production runs.

That's not a benchmark suite and the code isn't in this question anyway. We can't know if you performed a correct test or wrote something that just reused computed values due to JIT optimizations. BDN is the de-facto standard for benchmarking in .NET, used by the .NET team itself. People simply won't pay attention to anything that doesn't come with a BDN benchmark

and I did indeed verify, using dottrace, that if I type out things like new MyDouble(myDouble.Value + scalar * myOtherDouble.Value) the final performance is as good as if I was using raw doubles, to the extent that I can measure it. Since we seem to be getting sidetracked, may I ask: Do you or do you not think there is a chance to achieve what I want without serious performance penalties for floating point arithmetic?

Post the BDN benchmark code and results in the question itself. We can't replicate anything from comments. Do you or do you not think there is a chance I think there may not even be an issue to begin with. Post the code

What use is a benchmark suite if I can observe that the actual application that I'm running becomes measurably slower?

i'll have a look at BDN. Not familiar with it

@PanagiotisKanavos Added a benchmark that shows a 4x slowdown (and a 2x slowdown still after manual inlining -- not sure why the "manual inlining" looked fine in my real-life examples, but obviously they do quite a bit more and different things).

@KlausGütter Added a benchmark that shows a 4x slowdown (and yes, I did always run in release mode)

You're probably experiencing the overhead of calling a method. Try adding [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)] to the operators.

@ColeTobin Doesn't change anything (already mentioned this in the OP, it's just difficult to add that to the benchmark code without making it overly complex)

Going by the asm on sharplab.io (unfortunately the link would be too long and URL shorteners were banned so I guess you just have to trust me?) it doesn't look that bad, and suggested problems did not occur: operators are already inlined, no "objects" are created / no ctors called. The only thing that stood out to me is something that happens in all 3 versions: array bounds checks were not eliminated.

@user555045 I trust you, but am not sure what to do with it: Does the ASM even matter when everything may or may not be JITted? I'm also not sure what you mean by "doesn't look that bad". Do you have a guess then what's causing the slowdown reported in my benchmark?

(btw, I reckon I could eliminate the boundchecks by not using N but array.Length in the loops, but since this affects all examples equally, it's probably not worth looking into)

Your struct is as performant as it will get. Well done! You cannot make it as fast as a double since, well, it's not a double. What did you expect? That the creation of the struct would cost nothing? Similarly, reading a field is indeed cheap, but not completely free.

@l33t your comment would be unnecessarily sardonic even if you had made valid points. How does your sentiment that "structs couldn't possibly be free" agree with the observations that (1) an array of MyDouble is, in memory, literally just an array of double (as evidenced by the fact that you can memory marshal it to a Span<double>). Thus, there is no "creation of a struct", in terms of what's actually happening in memory. (2) There are other languages where this kind of wrapper can be inlined entirely, yet you made your claims without any explanation what makes C# different.

Sorry, I didn't mean to be sardonic. My point was that your struct is indeed perfectly written. I wouldn't know exactly why it is not inlined, but a public type will for put some constraints on the optimizer. Try making it internal and see if that helps.

Thanks, I'll try that and report back.

@l33t Making MyDouble internal (which required replacing the operators by regular static functions) didn't make a difference, also not when combined with the AggressiveInlining attribute

.NET optimization is pretty much a blackbox. I'd ask the Roslyn team directly.

@l33t good news from over there: performance overhead disappears in .NET8 https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/discussions/74475
